Has anyone experienced error getting Html.Glass().GetRenderingParameter<.....> on Sitecore 10.4
Using Glass Mapper Version 5 (Glass.Mapper.Sc.10 packages) on Sitecore 10.4.
In cshtml views, I have this statement -> var renderingParams = Html.Glass().GetRenderingParameters<FNBOnline.Feature.Product.Models.IPromoBannerRenderingParams>(), but it is failing with NULL object error.
In debugging the code, I see in line 79 the values are returned as "parameters" variable from Sitecore. But in line 80 it throws the error below. This happens on every view where I call this method (with other data). This worked fine in Sitecore 10.3, but it gives this error on 10.4.

public T GetRenderingParameters<T>() where T : class
{
    if (RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string parameters = 
      RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering["Parameters"];
    return GlassHtml.GetRenderingParameters<T>(parameters);
}

The Exception:
Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.Helpers.ItemPathBuilder.GetRelativePath(Item item, SiteInfo site)
   at Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.Helpers.ItemPathBuilder.Build(Item item, SiteInfo site)
   at Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder.UpdateItemPathParts(Item item, UrlBuildModel model, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder.Build(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreVersionAbstractions.GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions urlOptions) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreVersionAbstractions.cs:line 38
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreInfoMapper.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Setup>b__9(Item item, GetOptionsSc getOptions) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\SitecoreInfoMapper.cs:line 204
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreInfoMapper.MapToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\SitecoreInfoMapper.cs:line 128
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.LoadValue(AbstractPropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateInterface\InterfacePropertyInterceptor.cs:line 121
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.LoadAllValues() in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateInterface\InterfacePropertyInterceptor.cs:line 132
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor..ctor(ObjectConstructionArgs args, LazyLoadingHelper lazyLoadingHelper) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateInterface\InterfacePropertyInterceptor.cs:line 43


Hi Jose, I too getting similar issue on Sitecore 10.4. I did not find any nuget with Glass.Mapper.Sc.104. So I referred Glass.Mapper.Sc.103 nuget package. Please let me know if you find a solution or alternative.

Glass Mapper for 10.4 was just launched 3 days ago. You can try it out and see if you have the same problem.

I just added the new  Glass.Mapper.Sc.104 version 5.8.185 yet I still get the same error
